# Random variable $X$ takes non-negative integer values $n \ge 0$ with probability $p_n=\frac{A k^n}{n!}$. Find $A$ and $k$ if $E(X)=a.$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Random variable $X$ takes non-negative integer values $n \ge 0$ with probability $p_n=\frac{A k^n}{n!}$. Find $A$ and $k$ if $E(X)=a.$

My work.

$E(X)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{A k^n n}{n!}=Ak\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{k^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}=Ake^k=a$

So I got $Ake^k=a$. I am not sure how continue from here.

Comment: You should also use the fact that $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty p_n = 1$.

Comment: @angryavian ohh thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

From
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty p_n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {Ak^n}{n!}=1
$$
we see immediately that that $A = e^{-k}$, and further that
$$
\mathbb E[X] = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{e^{-k}k^n}{(n-1)!} = k = a.
$$